# Determine if one-point samples are significantly different from a set-of-values sample

Tags: statistical-significance, anova

Well, I have a sample x made up of 28 cases, sample y -> one case, sample z -> one case. I would like to determine if y and/or z are significantly different from x.
It's not possible to take more measurements for neither y or z.

Data look as follows:

```
x             y            z

0.72981354    37.13        67.4
1.518328503
1.655629139
2.563412415
3.027129131
4.480875623
4.545650835
4.762517086
5.065794539
5.643197549
6.674587177
7.019766786
7.687576876
8.321129011
9.798331225
19.22282133
25.73062098
```

I would like to know what would be the most appropriate statistical test to use?

I know that in order to use one-way ANOVA, I need at least two measurements per sample. So, is there another way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

If your $x$ cases are i.i.d. and you are willing to assume a parametric distribution $F_X(\cdot|\theta)$, you could

1. estimate the parameters $\theta$ using the observations $x$ and then
2. calculate the "tail probability" that an observation is as large as or greater than $y$: $1-F_X(y|\theta)$.

If the tail probability is very small, $y$ seems unlikely to have been generated by $X$. However, the estimation uncertainty associated with $\theta$ will make the "tail probability" uncertain. You could account for that by, for example,

1. obtaining bootstrap samples from the original sample and
2. estimating $\theta$ and calculating $F_X(y|\theta)$ for each bootstrap sample.

You would obtain a "cloud" of "tail probabilities", so you would have some idea about their distribution. But that could create a false sense of reliability; recall that you only have one $y$! Therefore, the inference will be quite uncertain anyway.

However, it seems that $x$ are not i.i.d. as they are increasing (unless you have ordered them increasingly before posting), so the above method will not work as is. Perhaps you could modify and adapt the underlying idea, though.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer! However, I forgot to tell that I am a biologist :) , so I would appreciate if you can simplify your answer.

Other notices:

- x,y and z are independent samples

- x has been ordered in an ascending order before posting.

Comment: Simplification: if you assume that $x$ is normally distributed with mean $\mu$ and variance $\sigma^2$, you could estimate the empirical mean $\bar{x}$ and empirical variance $\hat{\sigma}^2$ and calculate the "tail probability" $1-F(y|\bar{x},\hat{\sigma}^2)$. Of course, $x$ can have any other distribution, not necessarily normal. In general, I am not too sure of my suggested method. With just one $y$ there is little you can conclude with any reliability.

Comment: Samples are independent but not necessarily identically distributed. I am not trying to know if y is generated by x. I just would like to know if they are statistically significantly different.

Comment: Since you did not provide a definition of what is "different", I used a general approach where "different" deals with different underlying probability distributions. It's bed time for me now, but I may look at this tomorrow.

Comment: Thank you so much. I am sorry for keeping you late. Have a very good night!

Comment: It would help if you defined what is "different" for you. If $x$'s are not identically distributed, then $x_i$ is generally "different" from $x_j$. How can you then ask whether $y$ is "different" from $x$'s? Perhaps $y$ is "different" from $x_1$ but not "different" from $x_2$. There could be some particular characteristic that is the same for all $x$'s and you would ask whether that characteristic of $y$ matches the one for $x$'s. That would make sense. E.g. all the $x$'s have the same population mean (but otherwise different distributions) and you could ask whether $y$ has the same mean.